# HTML 5 Structure tags demo

Tags: html, tags, demo

i can't find demo of structure tags `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<articles>` ...
http://brucelawson.co.uk/tests/html5-elements.html 
Here, something like this, but with highlighted of each elements 
Please, help

Comment: demo = example of html 5 page :)

Comment: Here's why HTML is great: you can copy his example, paste it into a text editor, save it as "test.html", add water, then open it in your browser. 

Instant demo!

Comment: But how use highlighted of section(<header>, <foter>, <articles>)?

Answer (score 5):

There a good article at list apart (as usual) :
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5

For a simple structure, it's posible to enclose 'article' and 'aside' inside a 'section' but this not mandatory if you have only one section.

For example :

```
<header>...</header>
<section>
  <article>...</article>
  <aside>...</aside>
</section>
<footer>...</footer>
```

is the same than :

```
<header>...</header>
  <article>...</article>
  <aside>...</aside>>
<footer>...</footer>
```

But as this tags are very flexibles they are not fixed to one place, for example :

```
<header>...</header>
<section>
  <header>...</header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <aside id="navbar1">...</aside>
  <article>
    <header>...</header>
    <section>...</section>
    <aside>...</aside>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </article>
  <aside id="navbar2">...</aside>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</section>
</section>...</section>
<nav>...<nav>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two great resources are [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) and [HTML5 Gallery](http://html5gallery.com/). They offer detailed articles on how to use new HTML5 tags and examples of sites using them, respectively.

Comment: http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/tests/html5-elements.html
Here, something like this, but with highlighted of each elements

Answer (score 0):

The post above is correct, but the navigation tools should use the `<nav>` tag, that is more semantic code.
(note: don't use the section tag for a global container, use `<div id="main">` or even `<body>` with the rearranged header and footer):

```
<header>...</header>
<div id="main">
  <header>...</header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <aside class="nav_container">
    <nav id="navbar1">...<nav>
  </aside>
  <article>
    <header>...</header>
    <section>...</section>
    <aside>...</aside>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </article>
  <aside class="nav_container">
    <nav id="navbar2">...<nav>
  </aside>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
</section>...</section>
<nav>...<nav>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduction with html5 is best way